# Sum of cell in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I am trying to find the number of occurrences of "the" in a file that I have read into MATLAB. I have the following code `n=strfind(z,'the')` where z is the cell that all my lines are stored into.  It finds all the occurrences but I am unsure how to sum them up to get a number. I tried using `sum` but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  I tried with several data sets and I don't get any errors, just the `sum` you need. :)

Answer (score 2):

strfind will return [] if the supplied string is not found.
cell2mat will remove empty values from a cell array and just return the indices of the found string.

Therefore, you just need the length of the returned vector

```
z = {'Testing','Another','the', 'And the'};
n=length(cell2mat(strfind(z,'the')))


n =

     3
```

Comment: After trying this I get an error that is saying the cat arguments are not consistent.

Comment: I presume z is a cell vector of strings.  I've tested the code above with 0, 1, 2 & many 'the' entries per cell.  Can you check the output at each stage (strfind & cell2mat)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `cellfun` to operate on the output of `strfind` so that you can use `sum` as you would like to do:

```
sum(cellfun(@numel,strfind(z,'the')))
```